# Assume a homomorphism of groups gives a full and faithful functor on reps. Was it surjective?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, category-theory, representation-theory

Let $\phi: H \to G$ be a finite group homomorphism. Then there is a functor on representations $\operatorname{Rep}(\phi): \operatorname{Rep}(G) \to \operatorname{Rep}(H)$ given by precomposition with $\phi$.

Assume $\operatorname{Rep}(\phi)$ is fully faithful. Is $\phi$ surjective?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me call your functor $\phi^{\ast}$. It has a left adjoint (induction) which I'll call $\phi_{\ast}$. You want to know when the natural map

$$\text{Hom}(V, W) \to \text{Hom}(\phi^{\ast} V, \phi^{\ast} W)$$

is an isomorphism. Applying the adjunction, you equivalently want to know when the natural map

$$\text{Hom}(V, W) \to \text{Hom}(\phi_{\ast} \phi^{\ast} V, W)$$

is an isomorphism. By the Yoneda lemma this is equivalent to asking when the natural map

$$\phi_{\ast} \phi^{\ast} V \to V$$

(the counit of the adjunction) is an isomorphism. But $\phi_{\ast} \phi^{\ast}$ multiplies the dimension of a representation by the index $[G : H]$, so we conclude that this is only possible if $[G : H] = 1$.

Comment: "This" is the "correct" answer. +1

Comment: Very elegant. Still, I'm quite confused. Take a full monoidal subcategory of $\operatorname{Rep}(H)$. One can restrict the fibre functor of $\operatorname{Rep}(H)$ to a fibre functor of the subcategory, so it's a category $\operatorname{Rep}(G)$. One can also restrict the automorphisms of the fibre functor of $H$ to automorphisms of $G$, giving a group homomorphism $\phi: H \to G$, but we can conclude that the full inclusion is not $\phi^*$?

Comment: @Turion: I don't really understand your question. First of all, it's certainly not true that every full monoidal subcategory of $\text{Rep}(H)$ has the form $\text{Rep}(G)$ for some $G$; at the very least you should require closure under direct sums. If all of the right Tannakian hypotheses are satisfied, then yes, I think it's true that the full inclusion is $\phi^{\ast}$; what makes you think it's not?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, right, I should have said "full fusion subcategory", so I require closure under direct sums. Right, $\phi^*$ should be that full inclusion. I was confusing $G$ and $H$. So I'm interpreting $[G:H] = 1$ as being the index of the image of $H$ under $\phi$, so it's surjective. Great.

Comment: @Turion: that's still not enough, I think; at the very least you should also require closure under taking direct summands.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, the notion of full fusion subcategory I'm used to is such that the subcategory is fusion again. So in this example, in particular, it should be Tannakian.

Answer (score 2):

We may replace $H$ by $\phi(H)$ and thus assume $H$ is just a subgroup of $G$, since an $H$-equivariant map between representations in the image of $\operatorname{Rep}(\phi)$ is the same thing as a $\phi(H)$-equivariant map between them.  Now consider the regular representation $V=k[G]$ of $G$.  Note that a $G$-equivariant endomorphism $T:V\to V$ is determined by $T(1)$, since $1$ generates $V$ as a $k[G]$-module.  But as an $H$-representation, $V$ splits as a direct sum of copies of the regular representation $k[H]$, with one copy for each coset of $H$ in $G$.  On each direct summand, we can define an $H$-equivariant endomorphism by right-multiplication by any element of $k[H]$.  In particular, if $T:V\to V$ is $H$-equivariant, $T(1)$ only determines $T$ on the summand corresponding to the coset of $1$.  Thus if $H$ is not all of $G$ (and so there is more than one coset), there are $H$-equivariant endomorphisms of $V$ that are not $G$-equivariant.